# Large HashMap in java can be stored?

Tags: java, memory, hashmap

I know hashmaps are a great way to store keys and their values. Lets say I want to store the count of millions of words, or for concreteness lets say I have a file of 512 GB and my hashmap can in the worse case be 512 GB (String, Integer).

If I have a RAM of 8GB, can I store all of the hashmap on my computer? Assuming I have secondary storage of 1 TB?

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: This is not clear. If you have a RAM of 8GB, you can't create a map of 512GB. Well, assuming you don't use virtual memory, which would make work very slow. You'd do better if you use some sort of database in such a case.

Comment: @RealSkeptic so java stores all its variables only in main memory?

Comment: Basically, it stores all its objects in the heap, which is allocated from the machine's available memory, which, if larger than the machine's RAM, may partially be relegated to disk, however this is a non-optimal setup that should be avoided.

Comment: 512 GB o files? you will need *A LOT* more then 8GB of ram

Answer (score 2):

> lets say I have a file of 512 GB and my hashmap can in the worse case
>   be 512 GB (String, Integer).

You cannot determinate the size of the memory occupied by the HEAP in this way.
The file encoding matters and Java objects have also specificities that have effects on the used memory: fields in the class, `String` instances may be also cached, etc...

Anyway, loading in memory a file that does 512 GB is generally a bad idea.
As well as storing in a map several hundred of GB of objects.

Database are designed to do this kind of things.
To improve the access performance, you can still use an applicative cache that caches the results of the most frequent accessed data.

Comment: So the answer is that the memory would overflow? what could be the maximum size of the hasmap that could be stored? (out of curiosity?)

Comment: An `OutOfMemoryError` is very likely. As said, it is very hard to evaluate like  that. Why not try ? Increment a counter at each value added in the map and display this counter, you would have the exact size. You could also use tools as JVisualVM to monitor used memory and understand how the map uses this memory

Comment: @davidxxx if you use java8 you will no longer encounter OutOfMemoryError. Check this [Java 8 Metaspace](https://www.quora.com/How-is-garbage-in-Java-8-Metaspace-collected)

Comment: @Jose Praveen  In Java 8, metaspace addresses the problem of the permgen out of memorry error not which one of the heap out of memorry error.